# Is there a way to stop VS2008 Web Deployment Project from creating Source folder when using ExcludeFromBuild?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, web-deployment-project

When excluding files in Web Deployment Project using `ExcludeFromBuild` e.g.

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <ExcludeFromBuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\**\*.csproj*"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I end up with a `Source` folder containing all next to the `Release` and `Debug` folders. This folder does not show up if I don't use any `ExcludeFromBuild` option.

Is there a way to stop this folder from being created? Why is it created in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Misrosoft.WebDeployments.targets file (which web deployment project file imports) there's a _CopyBeforeBuild target which copies all the source files when ExcludeFromBuild property isn't empty or EnableCopyBeforeBuild is specified:

```
...

<CopyBeforeBuildTargetPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Source</CopyBeforeBuildTargetPath>

...

<Target Name="_CopyBeforeBuild" Condition=" '$(EnableCopyBeforeBuild)' == 'true' or '@(ExcludeFromBuild)' != ''  ">
    ...
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(CopyBeforeBuildTargetPath)"/>
    <MakeDir Directories="$(CopyBeforeBuildTargetPath)"/>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(_WebFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(CopyBeforeBuildTargetPath)\%(_WebFiles.SubFolder)%(_WebFiles.RecursiveDir)" />
    ...
</Target>
```

So the script creates the source directory and doesn't remove it. That directory annoys me too so I add next lines to web deployment project file:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(CopyBeforeBuildTargetPath)" />
</Target>
```